# Financial Mathematics missing step for solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

[image]

I got the first line, but I got lost when they moved to the second step. Can someone please explain to me how they moved from the first to the second line? 
This I am aware of is just Algebra, but if you need additional information be free to ask.

Comment: That is a solution to the quadratic equation  on $j$, (the other one is $j=0$). See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticEquation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand:
$$(1+j)^2=1+2.1j$$
$$1+2j+j^2=1+2.1j$$
Take everything to one side:
$$j^2-0.1j=0$$
Factorize:
$$j(j-0.1)=0$$
Hence:
$j=0$ or $j=0.1$

In the scenario given there must be a reason for $j\neq0$ hence it is excluded.